# Can't authorize with post request in java

Tags: java, discord

I am trying to send a POST request to Discord but I cannot authorize my bot and every time I run my command I get a 403 response code. My token is not wrong because I can create a POST request with CURL and get the correct response

```java
    @Override
    public void doCommand(CommandEvent event) throws IOException {
        String jsonInputString = "{\"max_age\": 86400, \"max_uses\": 0, \"target_application_id\":880218394199220334, \"target_type\":2, \"temporary\": false, \"validate\": null}";
        String botToken = "*token*";
        String current = event.getMember().getVoiceState().getChannel().getId();
        URL url = new URL ("https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/" + current + "/invites");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bot " + botToken);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setDoOutput(true);

        try(OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
            byte[] input = jsonInputString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            os.write(input, 0, input.length);
        }
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String responseLine = null;
            while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(responseLine.trim());
            }
            event.reply(response.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: `response.append(responseLine.trim()).append("\r\n");`

Comment: `byte[] input = (jsonInputString + "\r\n").getB...` plus maybe `os.flush()`

Comment: Tried it, it didn't work

Comment: I would highly recommend using a proper http client. Since it seems like you're using JDA, you can just use `event.getJDA().getHttpClient()` to get the OkHttp client used by the library.

Comment: I'll try it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by using OkHttp instead of HttpUrlConnection

Thanks to Joop Eggen for this!

```java
    @Override
    public void doCommand(CommandEvent event) throws IOException {
        String current = event.getMember().getVoiceState().getChannel().getId();
        URL url = new URL ("https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/" + current + "/invites");
        String postBody = "{\"max_age\": \"86400\", \"max_uses\": 0, \"target_application_id\":\"880218394199220334\", \"target_type\":2, \"temporary\": false, \"validate\": null}";

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(
                MediaType.parse("application/json"), postBody);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(
                        new DefaultContentTypeInterceptor())
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        Response response = call.execute();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
        String code = obj.getString("code");
        event.reply("https://discord.com/invite/" + code);
        response.close();
    }
```

UPD: I tried using event.getJDA().getHttpClient(), but i couldn't authorize discord with it. Made my own client interceptor

```java
public class DefaultContentTypeInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {

        Config config = ConfigFactory.load();

        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
        Request requestWithUserAgent = originalRequest
                .newBuilder()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("Authorization", "Bot " + config.getString("token"))
                .build();

        return chain.proceed(requestWithUserAgent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 880218394199220334

That's *highly suspect*. The JSON spec doesn't say how large numbers get to be, but this number **is not a valid double**, it's that large. If you were to read in this JSON by way of simply `eval()`ing it in javascript (which is rather relevant, given that the JS in JSON stands for JavaScript), then this number gets mangled into 8.8021839419922035E17.

It is a bad idea to send IDs as numbers, ordinarily one would send them as strings instead. Try that - toss some `"` around em.

If that's not the problem, this question does not appear answerable: Nobody can reproduce this given that it's talking to a service we don't know about, and nothing in this question gives a clear idea. This wild stab in the dark is the best I can give you. You'd know more than anybody reading this question does: Find more information to include.

Comment: That's not a problem. JSON is valid, because i can send POST request through CURL without any problem.
I just can't authorize

Comment: `:\"880218394199220334\", ` would still be worth a try, despite curl.

Comment: but i'll cover it in quotes, thanks